# How can the ADMM algorithm be distributed?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading Boyd's tutorial paper on ADMM. One question I had after I reached the formulation of the algorithm on pp.14 is: how can the alternating or sequential fashion of x-minimization step and z-minimization step lead to a distributed/decentralized implementation of the algorithm, as claimed in the abstract? Thanks!

Comment: A Ph.D. thesis, by Rahul Mourya, has been defended (very recently: Feb. 1st, 2016) about efficient variants of ADMM in University of Saint Etienne (France). If you want to contact him, I will give you his mail address.

Comment: confirmed. thanks.